# Laravel Eloquent Query Builder Default Where Condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have News model, when i query news, i want it brings news where status = 1 as default.

```
News::all(); // select * from news where status = 1
News::where('anotherColumn',2)->get(); // select * from news where status = 1 and where category = 2
```

Is this possible? What i want is so similar to soft delete feature (it gets where deleted_at is not null and if all data is wanted withTrashed function can be used).

I looked docs but i couldn't find anything helpful. Also, i tried to handle it in construct at News model but it didn't worked either.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just extend the parent class and overwrite the where function. (This is the part where you could add your custom logic...)

Comment: Depends on the framework version. For 4.2+ you simply use `global scopes`. This is exactly what you need and that's the way `softDelete` feature works in v4.2+

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I normally override `newQuery()` for this. `newQuery()` is the method that Eloquent use to construct a new query.

```
class News extends Eloquent {

    public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true) {
        return parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted)
            ->where(status, '=', 1);
    }

}
```

Now your `News::all()` will only output your news with status = 1.

Comment: This also adds where clause to nested wheres. So to avoid this I am using it like below:
`public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true) {
        $query = parent::newQuery()
        if(!$this->dirty)
        {
            $query->where(status, '=', 1);
        }

        return $query;
    }`
This is a dirty shortcut way to handle, but I recommend to use global scope.

Comment: Any clues on how to make this work with relationships? I'm facing an issue using it with whereHas.

Comment: Why do you do "return parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
            ->where(status, '=', 1);" instead of just "return parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted)
            ->where(status, '=', 1);"
Seems like the value passed before it's being override.

Comment: @EmirHerrera Thanks for pointing out. That's actually my mistake. Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 15):

It's been already mentioned but here is a quick example using global scope which might be the best current solution since you wont have to override Eloquent methods and would result into the same behavior but with more control of your model.

Just add this to your model :

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('exclude_deleted', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->whereNull('deleted_at');
    });
}
```

You can also create a child Scope class and reuse it for multiple Models.

For more information, Laravel doc explained pretty much everything about it:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#global-scopes

Comment: Nice clean solution! Here is a link to the latest docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#anonymous-global-scopes

Answer (score 13):

I think the closes you'll get, without actually going in to change some core files...

is Query Scope...

Scopes allow you to easily re-use query logic in your models. To define a scope, simply prefix a model method with scope:

```
class News extends Eloquent {
   public function scopeStatus($query)
    {
     return $query->where('status', '=', 1);
    }
 }
```

Utilizing that scope

```
 $news  = News::status()->get();
 $news2  = News::status()->where('anotherColumn',2)->get();
```

Its not quite what you wanted...but its definitely a little shorter than typing

```
 News::where('status','=',1)->get();
```

over and over

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know this feature but it doesn't really help. ```News/*conditions*/->get()``` is called at so many places. I don't want to change all this lines.

Comment: Doesnt your IDE have a find/replace feature where you could just search for all instances of News::  and update with News::status()->, seems like a simple fix really

Comment: Thanks for your help and no offense, but why we use framework, oop language, models, views then? I think forcing such solutions teaches me a lot of things and gives me flexibility while coding. What you said is last solution for me.