# Filter user's access on request based on Laravel's model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table full of `Products`. But, for each user is only allowed a group of **Products** to see. This is done by the table **users_products_permissions**. Each user has an instance of `UsersPermissions` table. In this table I set a range of restrictions to be applied on the user, restrictions to say each product a user is allowed to "**see**". This is done by a 'weak' (That's how we call in brasilian portuguese) table composed **only** by `user_permission_id` and `product_id`.

By the time of the requesition the requester user will be logged, of course.

The questions rests on: **How to filter user's access to products based on it's restrictions?**

Without checking in every requisition, manually, if the  user model have access to this product. An automatic way, lets say...

In case any code is needed, just say it!

Comment: Can you give an example of what one of your "manual" queries looks like?Also, what kind of relationship do you currently have declared between users and products?

Comment: By "manually" I mean scopes (as you said below, @Jack). I didn't want to rewrite all my code for this. I already have the requests made without the restriction. I was looking to a method that could give me everything I need in the model, e. g., so it wasn't need to go all  the way on my controllers to apply the rule.

Comment: What does your controller code look like and what does your Product model look like?  Does your controller preform the query request on Product and you don't want to modify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 4.2:
Use a global scope to scope an entire model.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#global-scopes
and
http://softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-and-use-eloquent-global-scopes/

For 4.0:
http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/global-scope-model and
[Laravel Eloquent Query Builder Default Where Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484720/laravel-eloquent-query-builder-default-where-condition)

```
<?php

class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function newQuery()
    {
      return parent::newQuery()->where('permission', '=', 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use laravel 4.0 (sorry to not make that clear). It's only available for 4.2

Comment: It did, buddy... did exactaly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Query Scope for this. Scopes allow you to easily re-use query logic in your models. To define a scope, simply prefix a model method with scope:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function scopePopular($query)
    {
        return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
    }

    public function scopeWomen($query)
    {
        return $query->whereGender('W');
    }

}
```

Utilizing A Query Scope

```
$users = User::popular()->women()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

Comment: But I yet have to declare at the time I make the request. I was looking for something more automatic. Like a filter (not laravel's filter, I know).