# Exceeded maximum time error when overriding the newQuery on Laravel 4.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

So, I was trying to implement this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372717/filter-users-access-on-request-based-on-laravels-model/28504154#28504154) for my other question on the same subject... and it keeps givin me the exceeded time error. Any clues?

This is on my product model. It inherits from `Eloquent`.

```
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
{
    $user_permission = Auth::user()->permissions;

    if( $user_permission->master )
        return parent::newQuery();
    else if( $user_permission->web_service )
    {
        $allowed_ids = array();
        foreach( $user_permission->allowed_products()->get() as $allowed)
            $allowed_ids[] = $allowed->id;

        return parent::newQuery()->whereIn('id', $allowed_ids);
    }

    return parent::newQuery();
}
```

If the user is `master` there is no need to query scope on the request. But, if it isn't then I need to filter by the logged user's permissions.

UPDATE:

I tried the following code in a controller and it works alright:

```
$user_permission = Auth::user()->permissions;

echo "<PRE>"; print_r($user_permission->allowed_products()->get()); exit;
```

UPDATE 2:

Guys, I just found out that the problem was in this peace of code:

```
$allowed = Auth::user()->permissions()->first()->allowed_products()->get()->list('id');
```

It somehow give me an `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`. If I put the exact same code in a controller, works like a charm, though! I also tried to put it in a scope, also worked. This it's really grinding my gears!

Comment: are you sure about `$user_permission->allowed_products()->get()` returning properly..?

Comment: Return properly if it is in a controller... yes.

Comment: Break it down line by line. $user = $allowed = Auth::user(); $permissions=$user->permissions(); $first = $permissions->first(); $allowed_products = $first->allowed_products() etc. That'll narrow down the offending call. Based on your earlier comment, this shows it's the get(). If it works line by line, leave it be, line by line. Less confusing to debug anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elloquent has a function called newQuery. Controller does not. When you implement this function in a Model you are overriding the one in Elloquent. If you then invoke Elloquent methods that need a new query for your model before they can return, like `->allowed_products()->get()`. Then you are calling your own newQuery() method recursively. Since the user permissions have not changed, this results in infinite recursion. The only outcome can be a timeout because it will keep on trying to determine a filtered product list which causes your newQuery() method to be called, which tries to determine the filtered product list before returning the query, and so on.

When you put the method into a Controller, it is not overriding the Elloquent newQuery method so there is no infinite recursion when trying to get the allowed_product list.

It would be more efficient to apply the filter to the product query based on whether the id is in the user's allowed_products() list using `->whereExists()` and build up the same query as allowed_products() except now add condition that id from the query you are filtering is equal to the product id in the allowed products query. That way the filtering is done in the database instead of PHP and all is done in the same query so there is no recursion.

Comment: Yep. You have an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your update code works. `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` does not have any magic methods to call the relation functions, you should get an undefined method error trying to do that.

Can you try something like

```
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
{
    // Returns `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`
    $user_permission = Auth::user()->permissions;

    if ($user_permission->master)
    {
        return parent::newQuery();
    }
    else if ($user_permission->web_service)
    {
        // If here you was to call $user_permission->allowed_products()->get() not much is going to happen, besides probably getting an undefined method error.
        $allowed_ids = Auth::user()->permissions()->allowed_products()->get()->lists('id');

        return parent::newQuery()->whereIn('id', $allowed_ids);
    }

    return parent::newQuery();
}
```

Update: as per comments below I believe the problem is due to `newQuery()` being called multiple times as the code works just fine when called once in a controller. When this is applied to every query there is no need to collect all the IDs over and over again (assuming they're not going to change each time you call for them). Something such as the below will allow you to store these and only process them once per request rather than every time a query is run.

```
private $allowed_ids_cache = null;

public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
{
    $user_permission = Auth::user()->permissions;

    if ($user_permission->master)
    {
        return parent::newQuery();
    }
    else if ($user_permission->web_service)
    {
        if ($this->allowed_ids_cache === null)
        {
            $this->allowed_ids_cache = Auth::user()->permissions()->allowed_products()->get()->lists('id');
        }

        return parent::newQuery()->whereIn('id', $this->allowed_ids_cache);
    }

    return parent::newQuery();
}
```

Comment: received `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::allowed_products()` error... =/

Comment: And I only needs the `get` method.

Comment: @DennisBraga Okay, so your code is functioning correctly, its just taking too long that PHP is being killed? I think its probably best that you somehow cache the $allowed_ids variable so that its not recalculated each time a newQuery() is called, as that function is called quite a lot when running eloquent relations and such.

Comment: Well, I placed in a controller, and it worked alright! Does the model has any `boot` method where I can place such function?

Comment: Models do have a `boot` method you can use. The code is working fine and when in the controller its called just once, but `newQuery()` is called multiple times when accessing relations and all sorts. I would assume that is the problem which is why I suggested perhaps caching the `$allowed_ids` so you're only processing that once rather than every time `newQuery()` is called

Comment: Didn't work either! I'm just gonna quit my job! =/

But I do agree with what you said, when I put it into a scope, like `scopeAllowed`, it works like a charm.

Comment: I would have a look into having a poke at it with xdebug and having a look at what is actually causing the script to take that long. I suspect its several slower querys thats causing the timeout, not a single factor.

Comment: I did it using query builder! It was not the way I wanted, but I was the way I could get it to work! Thanks, anyway... of you get it to work on the Eloquent, though, the bounty it's yours!