# Laravel Default Where caluse

Tags: php, laravel, model

In Laravel Eloquent model, is it possible to set the Model so it would always use a default Where clause unless specified otherwise.

So for example turn this:

```
$activeRecords = Records::where('status','active')->get()
```

Into this:

```
$activeRecords = Records::all();
```

But if I would like to get inactive records I would have to tell it todo so

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484720/laravel-eloquent-query-builder-default-where-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the SoftDelete Trait ( http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#soft-deleting ) its not exactly the same as with your status flag but is quite a clean way of doing it.

By adding the deleted_at column to your schema and introducing the trait `use SoftDeletes;` on your model you can then delete records but they won't actually be removed from the database.

If you then did `Records::all()` you would see all records that haven't been deleted if you want the ones that have been deleted you can access then with the `withTrashed` method.

Answer (score 1):

As @ChetanAmeta suggested, I would overwrite `newQuery` method in the model class:

```
class Records extends Eloquent {

    public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true) {
        return parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
            ->where('status', 'active');
    }

}
```