# Join multiples fields from different tables with Laravel Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i try return multiples fields from different tables in just one request, example

```
  properties table
      -id
      -name
      -address

 rules table
    -id
    -checkin
   -propertyId
```

i hope a response just like that

```
 [
      id=>123,
      name=>Name,
     address=>Main Street,
     checkin:10:00
 ]
```

And i would like that this can be used by default in all futures request, all(), first(), get()

**Note: I can't use relationship because I need to join two tables in just one**

Comment: it's `one-many` why you can't use relationship?

Comment: this is ` one-one `, the reason is because i need use theses fields in multiples places on backend so i would like set this for all futures requests because with the relationship i need add with('checkIn')->first() or with('checkIn')->get() so i want use just ->first()  or get(). I dont know if this is possible to do.

Comment: You can either extend the default query builder of the model or add a defaultScope. Either way might add some compticity and doubt if is the way you should go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution set the default with on the property class to include the rule.

```
protected $with = ['rule'];
```

To fill you exact spec, add a checkin [getter](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on the property model and use the append property to add it to the serialization.

```
protected $appends = ['checkin'];

public function getCheckinAttribute()
{
    return $this->rule->checkin;
}
```

Comment: Yeah men!! perfect! is exactly what i need it. Thanks!!

Comment: Hope it helped, also if you go with the getter approach it would be smart to still eagler load it as you can end up with too many queries.

Comment: hey men you know how can do this for many fields? checkin, checkout, doorman, etc @mrhn

Comment: yes there is approaches, but i think this question is well answered and for other people let it be, make a new one and link it i will gladly answer it

Answer (score 0):

Extending the query builder
[Laravel Eloquent Query Builder Default Where Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484720/laravel-eloquent-query-builder-default-where-condition)

Applying logic for all your model queries

Or for the default scope

You could do it this was
https://laraveldaily.com/model-default-ordering-assigning-global-scope/